# проблема при установке через apt "Репозиторий ... не содержит файла Release"

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, apt

Выполнял инструкцию по установке отсюда https://unit.nginx.org/installation/#ubuntu для ubuntu 18.04, и на шаге
apt update получаю:
Репозиторий «https://packages.nginx.org/unit/ubuntu bionic Release» не содержит файла Release. Хотя насколько я вижу там все есть и для bionic и для более новых версий

> ```
> Download the NGINX signing key used for our repositories and packages and add it to apt’s keyring:
>
> # curl -sL https://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key | apt-key add -
>
> This eliminates the ‘packages cannot be authenticated’ warnings during installation.
>
> To configure Unit repository, create the following file named /etc/apt/sources.list.d/unit.list:
>
> deb https://packages.nginx.org/unit/ubuntu/ bionic unit
> deb-src https://packages.nginx.org/unit/ubuntu/ bionic unit
>
> Install Unit base package and additional packages you would like to use:
>
> # apt update
> # apt install unit
> # apt install unit-dev unit-go unit-jsc8 unit-jsc11 unit-perl \
>       unit-php unit-python2.7 unit-python3.6 unit-python3.7 unit-ruby
>
> # apt install unit
> # apt install unit-dev unit-go unit-jsc11 unit-perl \
>       unit-php unit-python2.7 unit-python3.7 unit-python3.8 unit-ruby
> ```

Comment: Весь текст ошибки выложите тоже, из того что есть сложно скать, что у вас за проблема. У вас может быть опечатка в `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/unit.list` его бы тоже прикрепить.

Comment: проблема в прокси, среди успешных строк не заметил, вы правы, не всю ошибку скинул, в итоге поправил /etc/apt/apt.conf и все нормально теперь
Игн:1 https://packages.nginx.org/unit/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Ошб:2 https://packages.nginx.org/unit/ubuntu bionic Release                                                                                                                   
  Could not handshake: Error in the pull function. [IP: 127.0.0.1 3128]